# Angular azure ad authentication with MSAL 2.0

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL2.0 with Angular 15 to implement AZURE AD authentication and access user profile using Microsoft graph api. And I get the below error,

POST - https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token 400 (Bad Request) - zone.js:1521

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to resolve this error.

Thank you!

Comment: This issue is resolved. Solution: I enabled MSAL2.0 for this application and it started working.